# Sendmail not working on ubuntu guest - unqualified host name

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, hostname, sendmail

I have a win7 host running ubuntu guest through vbox. it is configured with a bridged network adapter and I am using DHCP to assign an ip of 192.168.0.5 to the guest which is mapped to smartstart.dev in my windows hosts file. I havent done anything to hosts on the ubuntu side.

I am testing a website and need sendmail working. I have installed sendmail, but the mails aren't being sent. When i look through the mail error logs I can see lots of lines like this:

```
Jan 14 17:00:01 djw-ss sm-msp-queue[2771]: My unqualified host name (djw-ss) unknown; sleeping for retry
Jan 14 17:01:02 djw-ss sm-msp-queue[2771]: unable to qualify my own domain name (djw-ss) -- using short name
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this working? Strange thing is I have a similar setup on another vb - I dont think I've done anything different and it works just fine out of the box.

Answer (score 6):

Edit your `/etc/hosts` exactly as below:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.1.1   djw-ss.localdomain    djw-ss
```

Check in your `/var/log/mail.err` file for the time of the last errors you had.

Reboot the system.

In your `/var/log/mail.err` you should not have anymore errors in this logfile.

Comment: After changing it, instead of rebooting the system, you could open the log viewer, and then restart sendmail via `service sendmail restart`. If the above is still happening, it will sho in your logs

Answer (score 2):

djw-ss should resolve to your computer.

The easier way is to add djw-ss to you host file (in Ubuntu) as 127.0.0.1 alias.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in trying this. I have included djw-ss as an alias. But djw-ss was already an entry as 127.0.1.1, I have commented this out and done as you suggested but sendmail, still isn't working. I'm getting the same entries in the error log.